# Offline mode - Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using Firebase with Swift, with the persistence mode enabled.

I have a `tableview`, and a simple `observeEventType` (.childAdded).

But the problem I have, is that when I stop the app, and go in the dashboard of firebase and deletes some items in the list read by the ChildAdded listener, then if I go back to the app, it still exists there, and the childAdded event is still fired for these items, even if they don't exist.

Is this a normal behavior of the persistence mode?

I am using Swift, Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: Two questions: What version of the SDK are you using? And when you go back to the app from the dashboard are you online/offline?

Comment: I am using the last version, 2.4.3, with Pod. Yes, I am online, when I restarted the app. That is why I found it weird that the cache was still used.. Maybe I have something else that could be linked, sometimes, when I setValue with a completion block (online), the completion block is never reached, nothing is called,..

Comment: @DavidEast If now, in the AppDelegate, I put the persistenceEnabled on "false", this is working correctly.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?